Civicrm Search Menu Item worked fine on 5.73, now gives error on 5.74.4
The CiviCRM "Profile Search Form" menu item worked fine on 5.73.x but with the update to 5.74.4, it gives an error   Not sure what changed to cause this, as nothing has changed as far as the profile used for the search.
This on Joomla 4.4.5, PHP 8.1.29, CiviCRM 5.74.4
Any assistance would be appreciated.
